# Django Form Field Problems with Cloudinary's CloudinaryImage Class

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget, cloudinary

I've got a [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) form that is displaying a [ClearableFileInput](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0133d66734f5b0470436a22f5b85bdf7266bf1cf/django/forms/widgets.py#L335) for a [CloudinaryImage](https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/blob/6d897c51c4a46a4f0b7c746125759e36abd4a366/cloudinary/__init__.py#L61) (from [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/)).  Things are working great, except when I display the form field, I get a mangled href in the anchor element:

```
Currently: <a href="&lt;bound method CloudinaryImage.url of &lt;cloudinary.CloudinaryImage object at 0x10b3f4ad0&gt;&gt;">&lt;cloudinary.CloudinaryImage object at 0x10b3f4ad0&gt;</a> <input type="checkbox" name="logo-clear" id="logo-clear_id" /> <label for="logo-clear_id">Clear</label><br />Change: <input id="id_logo" type="file" name="logo" class="span4" />
```

Here is the template code I am using:

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    <label for="id_logo"><h3>{{ form.logo.label }}:</h3></label>
    {{ form.logo|add_class:"span4" }}
    <p>{{ form.logo.help_text }}</p>
</div>
```

The add_class part come from [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks).  I've taken the add_class part out with no change in the output.

Here is my form definition:

```
class OrganizationFormTheme(forms.ModelForm):
    pass

    class Meta:
        fields = ('logo',)
        model = Organization
```

It looks like Django is having problems with the CloudinaryImage's url function.  I suspect it is looking for a simple property rather than a function.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?  Should I subclass CloudinaryImage and rewrite the url function somehow?

Comment: Can you show your Form definition?

Comment: I decided to just build the form widget manually in my template.  Would be nice if I didn't have to though.

Comment: I had a similar error. You are referencing the method, not its output.

Comment: Exactly -- only it is Django's template code {{ form.logo }} that is referencing the method, not its output.  Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed there was a conflict between the `url` function and the `url` property.
We've changed the function to be `build_url` instead of `url`.

In addition, you can specify transformation parameters as the `url_options` parameter when calling the constructor of [CloudinaryImage](https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/blob/master/cloudinary/__init__.py#L61). Then you can use the `url` property for getting the full Cloudinary URL.

The fix is available in the latest release of the Python library: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cloudinary

Comment: I've changed my implementation so I can't check this solution -- but it sounds like you made a change that fixed the situtation.  Thanks for the attention and great service.